# Which part of Ramsey theorem denotes or implies that R(m,n) = R(n,m)?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, ramsey-theory

There is something in Ramsey Theorem that denotes that R(m,n) = R(n,m).
When I looked on Internet it's always written that by symmetry R(m,n) = R(n,m).

So, can any one explains to me that?

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I do not think "denotes" means what you think it means. Perhaps you meant something like "implies".

Comment: Thank you @HenningMakholm. I will appreciate it very much if know the answer.

Comment: Hint: $R(m,n)$ becomes $R(n,m)$ if you look at the _complement_ of each graph. (And the complement always has the same number of vertices, of course).

Comment: OK, understood.Thank u very much.